# ng2-smartTable add form doesn't close when we cancel the windows confirmation popup

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

i got an issue in my `smart table` when i try the `add` button inside it, the form stay even after a `event.confirm.reject();` see picture bellow:

[image]

the form, i'm talking about is framed into a red rectangle

here is my code:

component.html:

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (createConfirm)="addFuction($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

component.ts

```
 addFuction(event) {
   if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to create?')) {
     event.newData['libelle'] += ' + added in code';
     event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
   } else {
     console.log('test');
     event.confirm.reject();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug/error if you think so.

It doesn't close the add/edit-field, so that the user knows that the update/create didn't work/got canceled and can change the input data or close the add/edit-row himself.

Comment: thanks, i've found another way to do it, using some popup, but it explain a lot of things if it's a willing behaviour